# Is this a correct robots.txt file?

Tags: seo, google-search, google-adsense, robots.txt, googlebot

I would like to allow Googlebot and Mediapartners-Google (AdSense useragent) to crawl my website. So I have written below code inside my *robots.txt* file.

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow:  

User-agent: Mediapartners-Google
Disallow:  

Sitemap: http://website.com/sitemap.xml
```

Is the above *robots.txt* file is correctly written? Yes or no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Robots.txt* permits to you to block some web crawlers (not allowing), if you want to allow a specific crawler like Googlebot, just ignore it in your *robots.txt* (same for Mediapartners-Google).

Just take a look at [robots.txt of Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/robots.txt) for example.

If you don't want to block these two web crawlers and you don't want to focus on other web crawlers, your *robots.txt* must be like this:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /

Sitemap: http://example.com/sitemap.xml
```

Comment: @Danny: I have edited my answer to allow you to understand.

Comment: To not be confused, just put the `/` after `Allow`. With the slash, there is no problem with your _robots.txt_.

Answer (score -2):

No, that is not correct. The default behaviour is to allow everything.

Use this instead:

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /
```

If you want to allow everything to all User agents, try this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Comment: BlacKEagle is correct - as and easier way to generate them i tend to use this - http://www.mcanerin.com/EN/search-engine/robots-txt.asp

Comment: @ Sam: thanks
@Danny: where is your slash? I gave you the correct answer, you don't have to worry anymore.

Comment: @BlackEagle `The "User-agent: *" means this section applies to all robots. The "Disallow: /" tells the robot that it should not visit any pages on the site.` I read from this http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

Comment: @BlackEagle Please do not give wrong answer, other user will learn wrong

Comment: @BlackEagle: `Allow` exists for _robots.txt_.